# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :learncodings

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Am adding learncoding project to my project us module dependency but it shows  [this  error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcgYt.png).
Any one please help me. below gradle is my app's gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.droidacademy.codings"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/', 'src/main/assets/c_outputs']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim', 'src/main/res/layout-sw600dp']
        }
    }

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

}



repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-1.7.jar')
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.5'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation project(':learncodings')
```

}

and this is my module app's Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.whalts.learncoding"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Go to File\Settings\Gradle. Deselect the "Offline work" box.
If this didn't work Try to Invalidate Cache/Restart

Comment: [ Thanks for your answer but i have already tried those methods and am getting same error]